# Creating an Organization in Github Enterprise with the REST API

Tags: javascript, java, github, github-actions, github-enterprise

I am trying to automate the configuration of a Github Enterprise. This ofcourse starts with the organizations. Github has a REST API for this.

Whenever I run the script with secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN I get the error: "Resource not accessible by integration". 403

If I run the script with a fine grained pat with full permissions I get the error: "Not Found" 404

I am running this script from in a repository in an organization in the Enterprise where I am trying to make a new organization. Code below.

```
name: Config Enterprise
permissions:
  write-all
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main      
jobs:
  my-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20'  
      - run: npm install @octokit/action
      - run: node .github/actions/createORG.js
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

```
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/core");
const octokit = new Octokit({
    authorization: `token ${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`
  })

async function createORG(orgUserName, orgDisplayName, admin) {
    try {
        await octokit.request('POST /admin/organizations', {
            login: orgUserName,
            profile_name: orgDisplayName,
            admin: admin,
            headers: {
                authorization: `token ${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`,   
                 'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
               }
          });
          console.log("Created organization");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        
    }

}

createORG('DLW-TEST2-EMRE', 'DLW-TEST2-EMRE', 'igtene_dlwr')
```

Comment: I didn't find any API to create an organization on [the oficial GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/orgs?apiVersion=2022-11-28) to investigate your issue. Could you please share where you got this `/admin/organizations` endpoint from?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I got it here https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.12/rest/enterprise-admin/orgs?apiVersion=2022-11-28

Comment: It seems indeed that _This endpoint does not work with GitHub App user access tokens, GitHub App installation access tokens, or fine-grained personal access tokens._ It probably won't work for the Github action token according to [the permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token) you can set in the workflow file. Did you try using a PAT with just the `admin:org` (Full control of orgs and teams) and the `repo` (Full control of private repositories) permissions?

Comment: I did and got the same error (Not found 404)

Comment: It may be related to your implementation. I observed the solution on the documentation suggest using `auth: 'YOUR-TOKEN'` instead of `authorization` (as you shared in your question). Moreover, you shouldn't need to inform this header in the `await octokit.request` method call, as it's already set on the `octokit` const.